# How to set Chrome Dev Editor as default text editor in Xampp?

Tags: google-chrome, xampp

I'm using [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) as my solution stack and [Chrome Dev Editor](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor) as my text editor. Going to the Xampp control panel, I can choose a default text editor by clicking 'Config' and then browsing for my chosen editor.

Problem is, I can't find where Chrome Dev Editor is saved on my hard drive. Where should I browse to on my hard drive to find the editor?

Note: I'm using Xampp for Windows if that helps.

Also: Chrome Dev Editor isn't an available tag for me. Would be great if someone with 300+ reputation could create it?